# How to best implement one to many relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, backend

I am working with Laravel for the backend. I am wanting to save a model, let's say it is Shirts to my database. A shirt can have many different sizes, so i want to be able to save a record of shirts like so into my database:

```
{
   "name": "A good shirt",
   "descripton": "this shirt is very good",
   "price": "$100",
   "sizes": ["XL","L","M","S"]  <--------- what I want
}
```

My question is, how can I save implement this in my backend? How can I save an array of different sizes to my model AND make sure that when this record is saved, it meets one of the available shirt sizes? For example, I want to make sure that a shirt can only have sizes from small to extra large.

I thought about creating a new model called Shirt_Sizes and having the records be the available shirt sizes, then setting a foreign key in my Shirt Model to this. But I am having a difficult time figuring out how to save many shirt sizes to the Shirt model.

I am open to other suggestions that work outside of this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If a shirt has many sizes and the sizes can belong to many shirts then you must Define a *many to many* relationship, You can make a separate table `sizes` for shirts sizes and then create a second table `shirt_size` that contains `shirt_id` & `size_id` link them with a foreign key to your `shirts` & `sizes` table.

Then you will define the appropriate relationships between the two models

**Size Model**

```
class Size extends Model
   {
   // Get the shirts for this size.
   public function shirts()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Shirt::class, 'shirt_size', 'size_id', 'shirt_id');
   }
}
```

**Shirt Model**

```
class Shirt extends Model
{
   // Get the size for the shirt.
   public function sizes()
   {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'shirt_size', 'shirt_id', 'size_id');
   }
}
```

Then when you need to store a new shirt with the sizes, it depends on what you send with your request:

1. Sending an array of sizes `ids`:

   Then you will need to verify the ids using `validate`:

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
     'sizes.*.size_id' => 'required|integer|exists:sizes,id',
 ]);
```

2. Sending an array of sizes `names`:

   Then you will need to verify the names using `validate`:

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
     'sizes.*.size_name' => 'required|string|exists:sizes,name',
 ]);
```

Then after creating a shirt record you can use an the `attach()` method to save multiple sizes for a shirt:

```
foreach ($validatedData['sizes'] as $size){
   $shirt->sizes()->attach($size['size_id']);
}
```

**Or**

```
foreach ($validatedData['sizes'] as $size){
   $size_id  = Size::where('size_name',$size['name'])->get('id'));
   $shirt->sizes()->attach($size_id);
}
```

Comment: amazing answer thank you so much! Could you provide one more piece of information for me? When requesting all the shirts I want the shirt sizes to be included in the request as an array. I have thought of doing this with the "protected with" on shirts. Is this the best and easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, in your *shirt* model define `protected $with = ['sizes'];` that should load what you want.

Comment: what if I need to update the sizes later and take a size away for example

Comment: You can use the `detach($size_id)` which remove a size for a shirt.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you have is many-to-many relationships, that is, a shirt can have many sizes and one size can have many shirts, so I recommend creating two table tables as specified by the Laravel documentation.https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```html
shirt
    id - integer
    name - string
    description - string
    price - integer

sizes
    id - integer
    name - string

sizes_shirts
    shirt_id - integer
    size_id - integer
```

Your models look like:

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shirt extends Model
{
    /**
     * The sizes that belong to the shirt.
     */
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Size');
    }
}
```

How to save sizes for a shirt:

```
$sizes_ids = [1, 2, 3];
$shirt->sizes()->sync($sizes_ids);
```

How to get sizes for a shirt:

```
$sizes_of_shirt = $shirt->sizes;
```